# take user's input and then print the alphabet series

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, scanf

My aim is to take user's input and then print the alphabet series. Printing the alphabet series from the point the user entered the input.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char alpha_U;
    printf("Enter the letter from where you want in upper case: ");
    scanf("%c",alpha_U);
    
    for(char i = alpha_U; i <= 'Z'; i++){
        printf("%c",i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to write scanf(" %c", &alpha_U); That is you need to pass the address of the variable alpha_U. Also it is desirable to place a leading space in the format string to skip white spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am still learning, I am sorry for asking this , silly mistake from my side, I didn't stored the entered value. Thank You!

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also starting out with C so I apologize if I missed any details.

```
scanf("%c", alpha_U);
```

is missing & in the front of the variable. Corrected below.

```
scanf("%c",&alpha_U);
```

I rewrote the code so I can get the user input in the main function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char lowerCase,upperCase;
        printf("Enter one chacters to be capitalized\n");
        scanf("%c", &lowerCase);
        upperCase = toupper(lowerCase);
        printf("%c",upperCase);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited some spelling mistakes sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost fine, except for

`scanf("%c", alpha_U);`

which requires a pointer as second argument.

I am not expert of C or C++ programming, so the thing I would suggest you is to checkout the documentation on cplusplus.com.

Specifically, here is how scanf is documented:

https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

> The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the format string.

so in your case you should be doing

`scanf("%c", &alpha_U);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char alpha_U;
    printf("Enter the letter from where you want in upper case: ");
    scanf("%c", &alpha_U);//Here,you should add '&' before 'alpha_U'

    for (char i = alpha_U; i <= 'Z'; (int)i++) {//Then,add '(int)' before 'i'
        printf("%c", i);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar yet, I've corrected it now